# Avoid matching word in the middle of word

Tags: regex

Suppose I have a four strings:

```
s1 = ghgJirafa/com/Activity.java 
s2 = /santel/data/jira/JiraSDK.java   <- match "jira" in "jira" or "JiraSDK"
s3 = /priv/data/configJira.java       <- match "Jira" in "configJira"
s4 = /data/privJiracom/config.java
s5 = /a/data/conJiraig.java
```

I want to write *regex* which matches `jira` in strings `s2` and `s3` *not* in `s1` and `s4`, because in **s1, s4 and s5, 'jira'** is in the *middle of word* which I wanted to avoid it. I have used *case-insensitive* to match the `s3` as well.

This is my regex: `((?i)jira).*\.java`

Note, that

```
ghgJirafa   <- doesn't match, Jira in the middle of the ghgJirafa word
jira        <- match, jira is a whole word
JiraSDK     <- match, jira is in the beginning of the word JiraSDK
configJira  <- match, Jira is in the end of the word configJira
privJiracom <- doesn't match, Jira is in the middle of privJiracom
conJiraig   <- doesn't match, Jira is in the middle of conJiraig
```

I searched on the StackOverFlow as well Google but didn't find such answer. Also asked it on different channel of discord, but didn't get any response.

Comment: Only s2 has `jira` not in the middle of a word. Maybe https://regex101.com/r/14aYJI/1 but that's loose matching at the start. `middleofthisjira.string` would also be found.

Comment: `(?i)\bjira|jira\b` - word bounder `\b` is either before or after `jira`. Or `(?i)(\bjira|jira\b).*\.java$` if we want to match `.java` at the end

Comment: @user3783243 I think he is trying to take capital camel case as separators for words

Comment: Also s3 has ``Jira`` at the end [config**Jira**.java] which should be matched.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest

```
(?i)(\bjira|jira\b).*\.java
```

where we match either `\bjira` - *word bound* `\b` followed by `jira` (`jira` at the beginning) or `jira\b` - `jira` followed by *word bound* (`jira` at the end of the word).

You may want to add `$` (`(?i)(\bjira|jira\b).*\.java$`) in order to ensure `\.java` to be at the very end of the string

[fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/XNJjdU/1)